# What should I do in emergency mode where I got couldn't find amd

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, amd-graphics, bios, recovery-mode

Suddenly I'm facing this problem and searched for a solution, but I couldn't find anything. My laptop is a Lenovo g5070.

[image: error]

This probably happened when the electricity came back, cause I had a problem with it, and laptop was working well without any problem before that. I have one system only Ubuntu 18.04.

This is what happened when I used `journalctl -xb`:

[image: journalctl -xb output]

Comment: You need to give us **way** more details about your problem, and what you've tried to do to fix it.

Comment: The usual problem occurred in the last session (power outage, you doing something that created it, or in a dual boot environment something done in the other installed OS), even though it's not noticed until power off & turned back on, or a reboot. Personally I'd boot a 'live' media & look at what was there & what was done, `fsck` or file system check your ssd/hdd, but I'd really be trying to recall what was done in the last session or since last session (the best clue is what occurred before this boot)

Comment: sorry I posted the problem from mobile and attached screenshot but didn't appeared I'm trying now to post it again

Comment: I edit the post

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 0):

Your image is too large and cuts of important parts but it DOES tell you want to do: view the log. The part WHAT log you need to view is cut off though so you need to examine that.

The text probably states:

> Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to try again to boot into dafault mode. Press Enter for maintenance (or press control-D to continue):

If the same use "enter" to go into maintenance mode or control-D to continue. Then do a

```
journalctl -xb
```

to view the log to find the problem that have it stop. And ...

```
systemctl reboot
```

to reboot.

Comment: Thanks, I used the command and found the error with red line and posted it in the post

Answer (score 0):

Your machine has MCE (machine check exception) errors. This usually means a hardware problem. Is your CPU or RAM overclocked?

**However, let first your your filesystem...**

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier

  - `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Then let's check your memory...**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.